# How to create a contact us page in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I want to add a contact us form in the contact us page of my mediawiki site.I have downloaded the contact us extention and put it in extension folder and included it in LocalSetting.php file as below

```
wfLoadExtension('ContactPage');
$wgContactConfig['default'] = array(
    'RecipientUser' => 'User', // Must be the name of a valid account
    'SenderName' => 'Contact Form on ' . $wgSitename, // "Contact Form on" needs to be translated
    'SenderEmail' => null, // Defaults to $wgPasswordSender, may be changed as required
    'RequireDetails' => true, // Either "true" or "false" as required
    'IncludeIP' => true, // Either "true" or "false" as required
    'AdditionalFields' => array(
        'Text' => array(
            'label-message' => 'emailmessage',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'rows' => 20,
            'cols' => 80,
            'required' => true, // Either "true" or "false" as required
        ),
    ),
    // Added in MW 1.26
    'DisplayFormat' => 'table', // See HTMLForm documentation for available values.
    'RLModules' => array(), // Resource loader modules to add to the form display page.
    'RLStyleModules' => array(), // Resource loader CSS modules to add to the form display page.
);
```

I am using mediawiki-1.25.1.But its not working.

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

The extension [ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage) creates a page Special:Contact where people can send feedback, and the recipient of the email is the user specified in the first field. If the user WikiSysop is specified with

```
$wgContactConfig['default'] = array(
    'RecipientUser' => 'WikiSysop', // Must be the name of a valid account
    ...
);
```

Then WikiSysop has to configure an email in her/his account, and ContactPage will send the email there.

If there is a problem to send the email, you have to verify the user account has a confirmed email address, and to verify MediaWiki can send email (see [Manual:$wgSMTP](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSMTP) and [other parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings#Email_settings)).